# How to implement tabs in Android

Tags: android

How to implement tabs in Android. 

I am having a context. In that I want 3 tabs named Free,TOP,Paid.Clicking on each of the tab should open separate activity.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Clearly you did 0 googling before asking this.

Comment: Check this [Android's BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202475/2032561)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, follow [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) tutorial from the android page, it will explain how to implement a few tabs

What you will probably want to do is to create 3 separate activities and bind each of those to a tab, so when you click on a tab icon/header it will create an intent and call `startActivity` on the relevant activity

I've had a look into the following recently and have [documented my findings](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-using-intents-to-refresh-tab-content/) on creating tabs and refreshing tab views, might be a helpful read to you