# Best way to implement tabs in android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have read looked through some code that implements tabs on the bottom of the app's page. And there is no deprecated method/class inside the code, and to me it is a very easy and clean way to implements tabs.

But I heard the new way of implementing tabs is to use fragments.

So, which one is better? And why?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/edit_item_tab_host"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingTop="65px" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/edit_item_date_tab"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5px" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="date"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/edit_item_geocontext_tab"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5px" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="lieu"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/edit_item_text_tab"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5px" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity` class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        TabHost tab_host = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.edit_item_tab_host);
        // don't forget this setup before adding tabs from a tabhost using a xml view or you'll get an nullpointer exception
        tab_host.setup(); 

        TabSpec ts1 = tab_host.newTabSpec("TAB_DATE");
        ts1.setIndicator("tab1");
        ts1.setContent(R.id.edit_item_date_tab);
        tab_host.addTab(ts1);

        TabSpec ts2 = tab_host.newTabSpec("TAB_GEO");
        ts2.setIndicator("tab2");
        ts2.setContent(R.id.edit_item_geocontext_tab);
        tab_host.addTab(ts2);

        TabSpec ts3 = tab_host.newTabSpec("TAB_TEXT");
        ts3.setIndicator("tab3");
        ts3.setContent(R.id.edit_item_text_tab);
        tab_host.addTab(ts3);

        tab_host.setCurrentTab(0);




        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TabHost` cannot contain fragments (well, it can but it's really tricky) so I wouldn't recommend to use it today.

Fragments are the way to go, and if you want to implement the new Tab mechanism (which is integrated to the "new" `ActionBar` available on Android 3.0) and still support old android versions there is [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), an open-source project which facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all versions of Android with a single API.

A lot of popular apps uses this project nowadays (including Google apps) so it's worth looking at.

Comment: But the actionBar always returns null in nexus 5 devices
so what do i do in that case

Answer (score 0):

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an
> Activity.
>
> [The android developer guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Your question seems to be worded a little strangely. You are asking about `Tabs` being at the bottom of the page but asking if you should use `Fragments`. Those are two different topics.

Yes, you should use `Fragments`, it is the route android is taking and will continue to take for the future.

Having `Tabs` at the bottom of the screen or at the top is a design decision. Depends on what would be more comfortable for the user experience, really doesn't have a lot to do with `Fragments`.

Comment: ya, the point is not about the position of the tabs.
So the codes that I posted shouldn't be considered the right way for android developer to implement tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Google has introduced a new View called [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html), a standard Bottom Navigation bar for android applications. As per guidelines you can add upto 5 (standard) items and pretty much simple as android's NavigationView. 
Please do visit [Component Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#), to know more about designing.