# How to set TabStrip on the top in Bottom tabs with drawables in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I am developing a sample application for tablets using android 4.0. This application has no title bar/action bar and have full screen mode.

In this app I used Tabwidgets and sets the tabs on the bottom. Everything is running fine.
Now I want to following thing on tabstrips:

- Remove the bottom tab strip from the tabs
- Add the tab strips on the top of the tabs (Upward direction)
- Want to set a drawable (small indicator) on the tab strip on top
- Want to add moving effect on this drawables from last selected tabs to current tab  smoothly.

My main.xml is :

```
<TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

My current tabs look like :

[image]

But I want to look my tabs like as:

[image]

I have tried a lot of things but did not get a proper solution. Please guide me.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html See "Don't use bottom tab bars".

Comment: Yes CommonsWare. I know that use of bottom tabs are not a good practice. But this is my boundation to use tabs on the bottom. I also tried by replacing tabs with image view on the bottom like a bottom bar. But that also has some issue in front of me. So finally I decided to use bottom tabs. Can you please tell the solution of my problem. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: And any other approach to get tab like functionality with above effects?

Comment: It is better to use custom tabbar.

Comment: Check this [Android's BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202475/2032561)