# How to implement 3 tabs in fragment and 4 tabs on the bottom in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have 4 activities in android.
I want to implement 3 tabs in each activity and 4 tabs at bottom to control 4 activities.
For each activity, it has 3 fragments, and each tab control one fragment.
For 4 Tabs at bottom, they just navigate to 4 activities and there are no relationship among the activities.
What's the practical way to implement 4 bottom tabs?

Thanks in advance!

picture 1:  [first activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwJpR.png)
picture 2: [second activity!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y0VA.png)

Comment: Check this [Android's BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202475/2032561)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an XML file for the bottom tabs. It should be a horizontal LinearLayout (wrap_content height and match_parent width) with your four ImageView buttons that switch between activities. Each button's icon in the XML should have the unselected state. Each button should be wrap_content and layout_weight="1".

In each of your activity's XML, make the root view a RelativeLayout, include the bottom-tab layout XML described above, make it alignParentBottom="true", and put the rest of your content above the tabs.

In each activity's onCreate, find that Activity's ImageView button, and change the styling to the selected version. Also set listeners on the other buttons to launch the corresponding activities (you could use a shared helper function for this to share the code).

For the fragment tabs on each Activity, you can use the standard ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter that Google is encouraging.

Let me know if you need more details for any of this.

Comment: However, when I tap on one of the bottom tab, it launches another activity. I can see the transition to launch a new activity, which is not desired. When I implement 3 tabs in activity, and switch them over, it does not show any transition. I want that kind of behavior, which is smoother. In that case, users do not feel it totally changed to another activity. How to implement the bottom 4 tabs switch behavior same as the tabs switching inside one activity. Does my clarification clear? thanks!

Comment: Well, you said that they are different activities, so it is going to feel different than it does with the tabs. I can think of 2 options: 1) use overridePendingTransition (or JB's ActivityOptions) to suppress the standard activity transitions; 2) instead of using 4 different activities for the bottom buttons, you could have each of the fragments have 4 views, and the bottom button would hide the previous view and show the selected one in the current fragment. You would have to do it like that to keep the 3 fragments working properly with the FragmentPagerAdapter. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, make sense. I will try this and let you know the results.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm curious: which approach did you go with (overridePendingTransition or multiple views per fragment)?